# Помогите, пожалуйста, со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Честно говоря, запутался в пунктуации фразы: "Главврач сказал "в морг" - значит, в морг". Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания? Например, нужны ли тут кавычки и тире?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Главврач сказал: "В морг". Значит, в морг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все знаки поставлены правильно.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, части которого связаны значением обусловленности. Поэтому ставится тире, которое в устной речи соответствует паузе.

ЗНАЧИТ - вводное слово со значение "стало быть, следовательно".

Кавычками выделяем прямую речь, которая в данном случае является дополнением (упрощенный вариант ее оформления).

Comment: А почему в первом случае двое кавычек, а во втором одни?

Comment: В приведенном примере кавычками выделена вся фраза. Без кавычек это выглядит так: Главврач сказал "в морг" - значит, в морг.